# postgres counting one record twice if it meets certain criteria

Tags: postgresql, syntax, select

I thought that the query below would naturally do what I explain, but apparently not...

My table looks like this:

```
id | name | g | partner | g2
1 | John | M | Sam | M
2 | Devon | M | Mike | M
3 | Kurt | M | Susan | F
4 | Stacy | F | Bob | M
5 | Rosa | F | Rita | F
```

I'm trying to get the id where either the g or g2 value equals 'M'... But, a record where both the g and g2 values are 'M' should return two lines, not 1.

So, in the above sample data, I'm trying to return:

```
$q = pg_query("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE ( g = 'M' OR g2 = 'M' )");

1
1
2
2
3
4
```

But, it always returns:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query doesn't work because each row is returned only once whether it matches one or both of the conditions. To get what you want use two queries and use `UNION ALL` to combine the results:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE g = 'M'
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE g2 = 'M'
ORDER BY id
```

Result:

```
1
1
2
2
3
4
```

Answer (score -1):

you might try a UNION along these lines:

"SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE ( g = 'M') UNION SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE ( g2 = 'M')"

Hope this helps, Martin

Comment: `s/UNION/UNION ALL/`, plain `UNION` is equivalent to `SELECT DISTINCT`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE g = 'M'
UNION
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE g2 = 'M'
```